# MySQLI statement (stmt) init errors

Tags: php, database, mysqli

If I read the PHP documentation right I am suppose to use mysqli_stmt_init to create a variable that is suitable for stmt operations correct? I thought I was doing it correctly but it doesn't seem to be working properly. When I do as the documentation says it gives me an error:

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: invalid object or resource mysqli_stm"

```
$get_posts = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($get_posts, 'select * from Chatposts where Chatid = ? and and CPid > ? and Deleted = ? order by CPid desc limit ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($get_posts, 'iiii', $chatroomid, $lastpost, $deleted, $limit);
mysqli_stmt_execute($get_posts);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($get_posts, $newposts);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($get_posts);
mysqli_stmt_close($get_posts);
```

Can you see what I have done wrong here?

Comment: `and and CPid > ?` too many `and`.

Comment: Do error checking with `if (!$get_posts) echo mysqli_error($db);`

Comment: Ok it looks like it was the too many and's, thanks!

Comment: Can't remember for certain in MySQLi, but I don't think you can use `LIMIT ?`. The limit must be concatenated in with a variable, rather than binding a param.  Maybe it works in MySQLi - definitely does not work in PDO...

Comment: The PHP documentation shows them using a limit in one of their MySQLi examples `/* INSERT INTO .. SELECT */
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 150"); `

Comment: It isn't the use of `LIMIT` itself I questioned, but the use of a `?` placeholder as in `LIMIT ?` rather than `LIMIT $limit_var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is failing because of those double `and and` in:

```
? and and CPid
```

Therefore returning `FALSE` as a mysqli_statement.
`FALSE` is then inserted into the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` function leading to that error (because it accepts only valid `mysqli_stmt`).
Just delete one `and` and you'll be fine.

From mysqli_prepare:

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

It's good practice, though, to always check for query errors and such. You should *at least* check the value of the prepared statement with:

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($get_posts, 'select * from Chatposts where Chatid = ? and and CPid > ? and Deleted = ? order by CPid desc limit ?');
if (!empty(mysqli_error())) // exit or trigger error
```

I highly suggest to move to PDO. It has good exception handling that makes everything much easier, especially when something fails.